# When should you change 'Facility Manager' to 'Facilities Manager' or should it stay 'Facility Manager'?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, terminology, attributive-nouns

In a document I am correcting the manager of the building is referred to as the *Facilities Manager*. Should it be *Facility Manager* if they are only the manager of one building? And when would, if ever, the *Facility Manager* be referred to as the *Facilities Manager*? My Boss said that it should always be *Facilities Manager*.

Answer (score 2):

***Facility*** doesn't just mean building. A building may be a facility, but it will often contain many *facilities*. Toilets, workshops, computer labs, clean rooms, classrooms - all of those are facilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to *facility manager* and *facilities manager* generically (as common nouns, lowercase spelling), then either form might be acceptable. A [Google Ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=facility%20manager%2Cfacilities%20manager&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) *facility manager* being more common in American English and *facilities manager* more common in British English, but they are not far apart.

[image: Google NGram showing relative prevalence of 'facility manager' and 'facilities manager']

if you are talking about formal titles, it is in the interest of accuracy to keep the original form and not exchange it for another one. In other words, if an organization refers to one of its staff as *Facility Manager*, you should use *Facility Manager*. If someone introduces herself as the *Facilities Manager*, you should use *Facilities Manager*.

Since this is for work, however, the overriding rule will be to use whatever your organization or publication may prefer as a matter of house style. If your boss says to always use *facilities manager*, you are well-advised to follow your boss's instructions.

Second, *facility* can be defined with a broad range of scopes. It can refer to an entire complex of buildings, like NASA's [Michoud Assembly Facility](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/michoud/index.html). It can refer to a single [toilet](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74673). Even a small building may contain all manner of equipment and spaces, so it would not be inappropriate for someone to be the *facilities manager* of that building.

Answer (score 0):

**Facilities Manager or Facility Manager**. In terms of actual work (if the titles are used correctly) the **scope of work will vary** in scope.

**Facility Manager**, manages the complete building or site. Cleaning, Gardening, Maintenance, Car Parks etc.

**Facilities Manager** will usually be in charge of building maintenance (Lighting, heating, Air conditioning etc), but the scope may be more inclusive.

> **facility** noun (BUILDING) a place, especially including buildings, where a particular activity happens:  [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/facility?q=Facilities)
>
> **facilities** [ plural ]: the buildings, equipment, and services provided for a particular purpose: