# Which is correct, Facilities Management Agency, Facilities Management Company or Facility Mangement Company?

Tags: word-choice, difference, singular-vs-plural, terminology

I would like to know which one is suitable and correct from both language and business perspective.

> Facility management (or facilities management or FM)

I found it on Wikipedia. What is the difference between Facility and Facilities?

> Agency [google's definition]: a business or organization providing a particular service on behalf of another business, person, or group.

As far as I know, FM provide service on behalf of building developer and it is more like an agency.

Why most FM company call themselves as a company and not agency?

And if they are providing services to separate complexes, why don't they use Facilities Management instead of Facility Management?

Comment: Related question:  [When should you change 'Facility Manager' to 'Facilities Manager' or should it stay 'Facility Manager'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/199105)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOOD QUESTION. There is no exact answer. As the scope of work of actual companies using these titles has made the boundaries unclear.

**Which is correct, Facilities Management Agency, Facilities Management Company or Facility Management Company?**

**Facilities Management Company or Facility Management Company** In terms of actual work there is relatively no difference between these entities although having said that the scope of work may vary and/or any company/agency can decide to specialise in a particular field. The same as Construction companies can specialise.

**Facilities** tend to relate to the **individual facilities on a site**, Air conditioning and heating for example whereas **Facility** tends to relate to the site as a unit. for example an office block, a Prison or an Airport.

**Facility Management** could arguably be said to be **more comprehensive in scope** of work as "They may run the complete site" including cleaning, gardening and security as well as more technical aspects. However, this is not always the case as Facilities Management Companies are often looking to increase their scope and Facility Management companies do not always have complete control of a site as **Contracts are often offered in packages**.

> **facility** noun (BUILDING) a place, especially including buildings, where a particular activity happens: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/facility?q=Facilities)
>
> **facilities** B1 [ plural ]: the buildings, equipment, and services provided for a particular purpose:

**Agencies**, (although interchangeable with Companies in some peoples thoughts), tend (in the UK at least) to be more related to "Over sight" of projects and /or Labour (although this is not always the case) A good example would be a New Prison where a **Facilities Management Agency** possibly working for HMPS or the Main contractor would have **Over sight** of the **Facilities Management Company**(ies) actually doing the work. A cleaning Agency would often seem to be just another company but is most likely just coordinating sub contract cleaners and allocating them to clients.

> **agency** noun  a business that represents one group of people when dealing with another group: **or** ​a government organisation: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/agency?q=Agency)

Examples travel agency.... Central Intelligence Agency

Answer (score -2):

I have a degree in “Facility Management”. I don't know of any college in the USA where you can get a degree in “Facilities Management”. When I go to the restroom, that means I have to use the "facilities."

A facility is a building, while facilities usually refers to a single room with a single purpose.

Comment: This isn't very helpful. While  "facilities" is a commo9n euphemism for a bathroom or restroom, it has other meanings, including a set  of buildings. This doesn't really ansawer the question "why".